# How do I get to show the name of the array inside another array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

So I had a question in an interview and it says something like this: Find the tire with the best average score in all conditions and if a tire has scored less than 5 in any condition it is disqualified.

```
$tires=[
  'Desert'=>array('dry'=>10, 'wet'=>4, 'snow'=>1),  
  'Ocean'=>array('dry'=>6, 'wet'=>8, 'snow'=>6),  
  'RainForest'=>array('dry'=>6, 'wet'=>10, 'snow'=>6),  
  'Glacier'=>array('dry'=>4, 'wet'=>9, 'snow'=>10),  
  'Prairie'=>array('dry'=>7, 'wet'=>7, 'snow'=>7),  
];
$max=0;
foreach($tires as $key){
    $total=0;
    foreach($key as $condition=>$score){
        if($score>5){
            $total=$total+$score;
        }else{
            $total=-150000;
        }
    }
    $total=$total/3;
    if($total>$max){
        $max=$total;
        $bestTire=$key;
    }
}
echo $bestTire." is the best tire with the score: ".$max;
```

The output says:**Notice:** Array to string conversion in **C:\xampp...**
Array is the best tire with the score: 7.3333333333333

The question is how do I get to show the name 'RainForest' instead of 'Array'

Thank you

Comment: Your algorithm could generally use an improvement; take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have confusing names, fix them:

```
$tires=[
  'Desert'=>array('dry'=>10, 'wet'=>4, 'snow'=>1),  
  'Ocean'=>array('dry'=>6, 'wet'=>8, 'snow'=>6),  
  'RainForest'=>array('dry'=>6, 'wet'=>10, 'snow'=>6),  
  'Glacier'=>array('dry'=>4, 'wet'=>9, 'snow'=>10),  
  'Prairie'=>array('dry'=>7, 'wet'=>7, 'snow'=>7),  
];
$max=0;
foreach($tires as $tire => $conditions){ // note key and value
    $total=0;
    foreach($conditions as $condition => $score){ // note array name
        if($score>5){
            $total=$total+$score;
        }else{
            $total=-150000;
        }
    }
    $total=$total/3;
    if($total>$max){
        $max=$total;
        $bestTire = $tire; // note key name
    }
}
echo $bestTire." is the best tire with the score: ".$max;
```

Comment: So much for the socratic method.

Comment: @localheinz fixed

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$minimumScore = 5;

// remove tires that have a single rating less than minimum
$filtered = array_filter($tires, function (array $data) use ($minimumScore) {
    return min($data) >= $minimumScore;
});

// calculate scores as average of score per category
$scores = array_map(function (array $data) {
    return array_sum($data) / count($data);
}, $filtered);

// find maximum of scores
$bestScore = max($scores);

// find keys with the best score
$bestTires = array_keys($scores, $bestScore);

// there could be more than one tire with same score, pick the first
$bestTire = array_shift($bestTires);

echo sprintf(
    '%s is the best tire with the score: %s',
    $bestTire,
    $bestScore
);
```

For reference, see:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.max.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-Shift.php

For an example, see:

- https://3v4l.org/5L5Xn

Answer (score -2):

You should read about how `foreach()` works.

```
foreach($tires as $key => $value) {
    // $key is your tire name
    // $value is the array of data for that tire
}
```